# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

When selecting cd pod install

This error message is received
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly"

You have either:
out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `RNFBApp`.
You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.

[Full Error Message In Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Ga2.png)

[Documentation Setup Issue When Selecting cd pod install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f19p1.png)